# Compile MATLAB on Windows for UNIX

Tags: windows, matlab, unix, compilation

I currently have a Unix machine with the MATLAB runtime environment installed and a Windows machine with the MATLAB compiler installed.  I can compile and run the standalone successfully on the Windows box, but I cannot determine how to compile from Windows for UNIX.

Is this possible or would I need to compile on the UNIX machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible,  you have to compile again on your Unix machine,  unfortunately.

Comment: Is it possible to use the MATLAB compiler to generate the C code, then compile that on my UNIX machine?